# binary serach it not search element whereas it is in array

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search

The binarysearch function returns -1 even though the element is present in the array. Here's my code:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int binarysearch(int arr[],int n, int key){
    int s=0;
    int e=0;
    int mid=(s+e)/2;

    while (s<=e)
    {
        if(arr[mid]==key){
            return mid;
        }
        else if(arr[mid]<key){
            s=mid+1;
        }
        else{
            e=mid-1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int main (){
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter array size :";
    cin>>n;

    int arr[n];

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cin>>arr[i];
    }

    int key;
    cout<<"Enter key :";
    cin>>key;

    cout<<binarysearch(arr,n,key)<<endl;
}
```

For example if we input the following sample:

n = 5

key = 3

array = [2, 3, 6, 9, 12]

we get -1, even though 3 is present in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating the value of variable mid inside your while loop, also you need to make variable e equal to n-1 (because s and e define the range, and you current range consists of only one element - the first element). The code should look like this:

```cpp
int binarysearch(int arr[],int n, int key){
    int s=0;
    int e=n-1;
    
    while (s<=e)
    {
        int mid=(s+e)/2;
        if(arr[mid]==key){
            return mid;
        }
        else if(arr[mid]<key){
            s=mid+1;
        }
        else{
            e=mid-1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```